# Any commands to show what kernel features are included in the Docker base images?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I know base images are minimal operating systems with limited kernel features. If I want to use Ubuntu base image for my applications, how can I know if the kernel features included are enough for my applications? Are there any commands to show the kernel features included in the base images? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a common misconception regarding containerization vs virtualization.

A Docker image is just a packaged file structure with some additional metadata. A Docker container is simply an isolated process on the host (see [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)) using the image as its root file system (see [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)). This is what makes containers so lightweight as compared to running a full VM.

To answer your question, a Docker container can only rely on the kernel features of the host system it is running on.

If your application requires uncommon kernel features Docker might not be the best solution, though you could easily add a check for those features as part of the container startup to inform the user with further instructions.

Comment: Hello @Erik, thanks for your reply! So you were saying that if an app inside a container needs some kernel features, this will be provided by the host? But what about the security concerns? On the Docker website they said that the isolation makes the attack surface of a container small, so that "even if an intruder manages to escalate to root within a container, it will be much harder to do serious damage, or to escalate to the host". So on what cases do apps in containers can get host kernel features and on what cases they cannot? Thanks for your patience! :)

Comment: @Lena Generally Docker will only try to isolate the process in a container from other processes on the host. Other restrictions may apply, depending on the distribution used on the host ( SELinux, apparmor, etc) See the official docker [security primer](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/security/) for details.